# How to get the TARGET tables from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am aware of this query that can pull referenced tables from a SQL Server stored procedure.

For example, if I have this stored procedure:

```
UPDATE tbl1 
SET symbol = tbl2.symbol, symbol2 = tbl2.symbol2
FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.PK = tbl2.PK
```

This query:

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%TableNameOrWhatever%'
```

and this one:

```
SELECT
    o.name
FROM
    sys.sql_modules sm
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON
    o.object_id = sm.object_id
WHERE
    sm.definition LIKE '%<table name>%'
```

both return `tbl1` & `tbl2` as the response.

My question is this: `tb11` is ReadWrite as the SQL shows, and `tbl2` is ReadOnly.

How do I update my queries to make the distinction?

So my output should be:

```
Response
========
tbl1, ReadWrite
tbl2, ReadOnly
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean be "read/write" and "readonly" - you're only "updating" one table but that sort of meta-information is not maintained by SQL Server. You could look for the query text being `like '%update tbl1%'` and display whatever you want to indicate it's inserted into, but that would rely on the word *update* and the *tablename* being used, what if it was update and an *alias*?

Comment: Hey Stu, appreciate the comment.  the update query joins tb1 to tb2 which means two tables are being read to set the update, then tbl1 is updated.  this means tbl1 is read then written to, while tbl2 is not.  using a string context might give me mixed results as this is one of many types of sql that I"m interrogating.

Comment: this implies that tbl1 is the target, and I'm trying to make the distinction

Answer (score 0):

Try [sys.sql_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), eg

```
select  object_name(d.referenced_major_id) referenced_object, 
        object_name(d.object_id) referenced_by,  
        max(cast(d.is_updated as int)) is_updated
from sys.sql_dependencies d
join sys.objects o
  on d.object_id = o.object_id
where o.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
group by d.referenced_major_id, d.object_id
order by d.object_id
```

But beware that procedures with deferred name resolution and stored procedures that access tables with dynamic SQL won't be tracked

Comment: thanks David.  does is_updated work for UPDATES and INSERTS?

Comment: Per [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), `sql_dependencies` is deprecated.  Care to provide a more future-proof query using `sql_expression_dependencies` and/or `dm_sql_referenced_entities`?

Answer (score -1):

The DMV `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` contains this information.

The following query should get you exactly what you need

```sql
SELECT
  name,
  referenced_entity_name,
  is_updated
FROM sys.procedures p
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id) + '.' + p.name,'OBJECT') r
WHERE referenced_minor_name IS NULL;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d595a2faf8b554ef98c1a2d12bb2b926)